# List of Inherited Classes Listbox Class Name not Valid at this Point

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a WinForms application and I have a Listbox with a datasource of an `ObservableCollection<ParentClass>` and I am trying to set specific labels based on the subclass of the class. I get the error "Class name is not valid at this point". Sample code:

```
using System;    
public class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }

    public class ChildA : Parent
    {
        public ChildA() { }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<Parent> listBoxSource = 
               new ObservableCollection<Parent>();

        listBox.DataSource = listBoxSource;

    }

    private void customerListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
                 EventArgs e)
    {

        if (customerListBox.SelectedItem.GetType() ==
              Parent.ChildA) // <---Error Here
        {
            //Code Here
        }
    }    
}
```

Is there a better way to perform an action based on the type of an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
 if (customerListBox.SelectedItem.GetType() == Parent.ChildA)
```

to:

```
 if (customerListBox.SelectedItem is Parent.ChildA)
```

or as you was doing:

```
 if (customerListBox.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(Parent.ChildA))
```

Realize that using operator "is" avoid to check if the object is null.